# SQL where term is equals or like (two tables)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join, where-clause

With MySQL, I need to find all records where a column is like a term OR the term is equals a column but in another table.

For example:

```
select *
from table_a TA,
     table_b TB
where TB.number = '1447'
   or TA.subject like '%1447%'
```

In practice, I'm searching for a value, it can be on TB.number OR TA.subject. This SQL above is returning multiple records and it not matches the search.

Comment: Whats sis the common column between `table_a` & `table_b`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing a cross product of the two tables. You need to restrict the number of results using some JOIN criteria.

Read more on this here:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you need to do a `JOIN` among the table on a common column like

```
select * 
from table_a TA
join table_b TB 
on TA.id = TB.id
where TB.number = '1447' 
or TA.subject like '%1447%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table_a TA, table_b TB where TB.number = '1447'  
UNION ALL 
select * from table_a TA, table_b TB where TA.subject like '%1447%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the two table are more or less unrelated. Do a `UNION ALL` instead of `JOIN`:

```
select * from table_a TA where TA.subject like '%1447%'
UNION ALL 
select * from table_b TB where TB.number = '1447'
```